# How to debug the Procedure which is unable to update the column of a table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 2 Independent queries which are updating value into 4 NUMBER variables

```
DSL_HOUR_DIVISOR NUMBER (10);
ELEC_HOUR_DIVISOR NUMBER(10);
DSL_HOUR_DIVIDEND NUMBER(10);
ELEC_HOUR_DIVIDEND NUMBER(10);



SELECT SUM(SUB_SUB_ITEM_VALUE_DSL) AS SUB_SUB_ITEM_VALUE_DSL,
       SUM(SUB_SUB_ITEM_VALUE_ELEC) AS SUB_SUB_ITEM_VALUE_ELEC
  INTO DSL_HOUR_DIVIDEND,ELEC_HOUR_DIVIDEND 
  FROM (SELECT ITEM_NO,
               SUB_ITEM_NO,
               SUB_SUB_ITEM_NO,
               SUM(SUB_SUB_ITEM_VALUE_DSL) AS SUB_SUB_ITEM_VALUE_DSL,
               SUM(SUB_SUB_ITEM_VALUE_ELEC) AS SUB_SUB_ITEM_VALUE_ELEC
          FROM REPORT.DY_SUM_DLY_DAILY
         WHERE REPORT_DATE>='01-Mar-2020'
           AND REPORT_DATE<='07-Mar-2020'
           AND SUB_ITEM_NO=5.01
         GROUP BY ITEM_NO,
                  SUB_ITEM_NO,
                  SUB_SUB_ITEM_NO);   

SELECT SUM(SUB_SUB_ITEM_VALUE_DSL) AS SUB_SUB_ITEM_VALUE_DSL,
       SUM(SUB_SUB_ITEM_VALUE_ELEC) AS SUB_SUB_ITEM_VALUE_ELEC
  INTO DSL_HOUR_DIVISOR,ELEC_HOUR_DIVISOR 
  FROM (SELECT ITEM_NO,
               SUB_ITEM_NO,
               SUB_SUB_ITEM_NO,
               SUM(SUB_SUB_ITEM_VALUE_DSL) AS SUB_SUB_ITEM_VALUE_DSL, 
               SUM(SUB_SUB_ITEM_VALUE_ELEC) AS SUB_SUB_ITEM_VALUE_ELEC
          FROM REPORT.DY_SUM_DLY_DAILY
         WHERE REPORT_DATE>='01-Mar-2020'
           AND REPORT_DATE<='07-Mar-2020'
           AND SUB_ITEM_NO IN (5.04,5.05) 
         GROUP BY ITEM_NO, SUB_ITEM_NO, SUB_SUB_ITEM_NO);

UPDATE REPORT.GBL_TMP_SUMMARY_CNT A
   SET CY_DSL_CNT=ROUND(DSL_HOUR_DIVIDEND/DSL_HOUR_DIVISOR*100,2),
       CY_ELEC_CNT=ROUND(ELEC_HOUR_DIVIDEND/ELEC_HOUR_DIVISOR*100,2) 
 WHERE A.ITEM_NO=5
   AND A.SUB_ITEM_NO=5.06
   AND A.SUB_SUB_ITEM_NO='B';
COMMIT;
```

I tried Debugging the code by checking if any value is getting assigned to these 4 variables ,I even checked the percentage calculation which is updating the Column and all the 4 variables are getting assigned the value . These were the values printed

```
5.06 b DSL_HOUR_DIVIDEND---------------5555187
5.06 b ELEC_HOUR_DIVIDEND---------------6923284
5.06 b DSL_HOUR_DIVISOR---------------5575697
5.06 b ELEC_HOUR_DIVISOR---------------6937356
5.06 b Current year Diesl % ---------------99.63
5.06 b Current year Electric % ---------------99.8
```

But in the GBL_TMP_SUMMARY_CNT Table , values are not getting updated ,please guide me how to resolve this issue .Both the columns CY_DSL_CNT & CY_ELEC_CNT are of NUMBER(10,2) type .

Comment: Can you run the Select query of 1 set, and see whether the data is returned as per where clause. If that doesn't return anything try removing each condition separately.

Comment: I checked it , both the queries are returning values .

Comment: Then without the "Into Clause" can you check whether the outer select works

Comment: All the things are working , outer query without INTO & inner query

Comment: Just before the commit could you add dbms_output.put_line(" Rows updated "+SQL%ROWCOUNT); , also what are the values that you had printed, could you update the code with respective dbms_output so that we know what you tried to debug.

Comment: I had written                                                                                                                                          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' 5.06 b DSL_HOUR_DIVIDEND---------------'||DSL_HOUR_DIVIDEND);
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('5.06 b ELEC_HOUR_DIVIDEND---------------'||ELEC_HOUR_DIVIDEND);
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('5.06 b DSL_HOUR_DIVISOR---------------'||DSL_HOUR_DIVISOR);
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('5.06 b ELEC_HOUR_DIVISOR---------------'||ELEC_HOUR_DIVISOR);

Comment: And , I was getting values for all these print statements , I have also got Rows Updated as 1 just before commit as directed by you

Comment: What results do you get when you execute `SELECT ITEM_NO, SUB_ITEM_NO, SUB_SUB_ITEM_NO, CY_DSL_CNT, CY_ELEC_CNT FROM REPORT.GBL_TMP_SUMMARY_CNT WHERE ITEM_NO=5 AND SUB_ITEM_NO=5.06 AND SUB_SUB_ITEM_NO='B'`?

Comment: Can you check ddl of `GBL_TMP_SUMMARY_CNT`  I suspect global temporary table created without the  clause `on commit preserve rows`

Comment: Can you check
`SELECT ROUND(DSL_HOUR_DIVIDEND/DSL_HOUR_DIVISOR*100,2)`

and

`SELECT * FROM REPORT.GBL_TMP_SUMMARY_CNT A
WHERE A.ITEM_NO=5
   AND A.SUB_ITEM_NO=5.06
   AND A.SUB_SUB_ITEM_NO='B';`

Comment: The issue is resolved now , Thanks to all for your help

Comment: Do you mind in sharing what went wrong and add the answer? This might help developers in future as it is hard to believe the query to fail update when SQL%ROWCOUNT is 1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much to go on here but there is a difference in your `WHERE` clauses between your `select` and your `update` statements.

Your 1st `where` clause is `SUB_ITEM_NO=5.01` and your 2nd is `SUB_ITEM_NO IN (5.04,5.05)`.

However, your update `where` clauses are:

```
WHERE A.ITEM_NO=5
AND A.SUB_ITEM_NO=5.06
AND A.SUB_SUB_ITEM_NO='B'
```

That's a little inconsistent to me but I don't know your business logic.

What I would try is a `select` using the clauses above, to see whether you are actually getting any rows back.

If you're not, then there's nothing to update.

```
-- does this return any rows???
SELECT *
FROM REPORT.GBL_TMP_SUMMARY_CNT A
WHERE A.ITEM_NO=5
   AND A.SUB_ITEM_NO=5.06
   AND A.SUB_SUB_ITEM_NO='B';
```

Comment: The select & update are as per business logic , anyways I had got the problem in my code , thankss for the help